# Why flock() in fork() double blocks the same file with different descriptors?

Tags: c, fork, flock

When I run my code:

```
int i = fork();

if (!i){
    int id = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);
    if(flock(id, LOCK_EX) == 0)
        printf("child\n");
    close(id);
}
else {
    int id = open("shared.txt", 0600 | O_WRONLY);
    if(flock(id, LOCK_EX) == 0)
        printf("parent\n");
    close(id);
}

wait(NULL);
```

I expect that one process will block my file and the other process will not send my a message, because flock() returns -1. But either first and second flock() works with different file descriptors.

Comment: From `man 3 flock`: *"If a process uses open(2) (or similar) to obtain more than one descriptor for the same file, these descriptors are treated independently by flock(). An attempt to lock the file using one of these file descriptors **may** be denied by a lock that the calling process has already placed via another descriptor."* But your processes are locking and then immediately releasing the file, so it might be happening that they don't even try to lock the file simultaniously.

Comment: The code has possible timing issues — you can't tell how the calls will be sequenced.  It's possible for the child to complete before the parent locks the file.

Comment: @Eugene Sh., That quoted passage doesn't apply. No process is attempting to obtain more than one descriptor for the same file. Did you miss that `fork` is used?

Comment: @ikegami Indeed, it does not as is. Meaning that both processes can successfully lock the file one after the other. Pretty much the whole point of `flock`.

Comment: `fork()` returns `pid_t`, not `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect that one process will block my file and the other process will not send my a message

No, not at all.

Let's say one of the processes locks the file and the other tries to lock it. `flock` doesn't return. `flock` blocks until the file becomes unlocked. The process with the lock will output its message and exit, which releases the lock. The other process will now unblock, output its message and exit. Both processes will always output their messages (eventually).

There is a flag that will cause `flock` to return immediately if the file is locked: `LOCK_NB`. But even if you used `LOCK_NB`, this wouldn't guarantee that only one of the processes would output a message.

Let's say one of the processes locks the file, prints its message and exits before the other process even attempts to lock the file. Easily possible with the program you provided. The other process will have no problem obtaining a lock and thus output its message and exit. It's possible for both processes to output their messages.

> flock() returns -1

This does not indicate that the file is already locked; this indicates something went wrong.<sup>[1]</sup> Perhaps the `open` failed, so you provided an invalid file descriptor to `flock`. Both `open` and `flock` set `errno` on error, which you output using `perror`.

```c
int fd = open( ... );
if ( fd == -1 ) {
   // Error!
   perror( "open" );
   exit( 1 );
}

if ( flock( fd, LOCK_EX ) == -1 )
   // Error!
   perror( "flock" );
   exit( 1 );
}

...

close( fd );
```

---

1. It can indicate the file is already locked when `LOCK_NB` is used. `errno == EWOULDBLOCK` if that's the case. But you didn't use `LOCK_NB`.